# Show PHP result in div without refresh

Tags: php, html

Do you know a way to display a php result inside a div dynamically, without refreshing the page? 
For example, we have 2 divs: one on the top half of the page and one on the bottom of the page. The top one contains a form with 3 input fields. You type some values inside, then press a button. When you press the button, the bottom div displays the values without refreshing the page.

Comment: Use jquery ajax to insert and display the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with pure PHP because PHP is a static language. You have to use Javascript and AJAX.  I recommend using a library like Zepto or jQuery to make it easy to implement like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="search" />
    <input type="submit" />    
</form>

<div id="div2"></div>

<script>
    // When the form is submitted run this JS code
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        // Post the form data to page.php
        $.post('page.php', $(this).serialize(), function(resp) {
            // Set the response data into the #div2
            $('#div2').html(resp);
        });

        // Cancel the actual form post so the page doesn't refresh
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer, because this is the most complete answer. I only have to wait 8 more minutes, but I will.

Comment: What if I can't create a form, even if I have have input fields and I want this script to be started from an `<input type="button"...>` ?

Comment: You have to add an `onclick` to the button and then manually get each of the input's values and pass them to the jquery `$.post()` function

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it using AJAX. With Ajax you can exchange data with a server, make asynchronous request without refreshing the page.

Check this out to see how it can be implemented using Jquery:- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/